# How to change the position of a window scrollbar?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to change the position of the Vertical Scrollbar of a window?

I'm referring to the position in xy, **for example** set it in the middle of the window instead of the edges.

[image: Scrollbar]

Comment: You probably want [ScrollWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindow) or [ScrollWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindowex) or [SetScrollInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setscrollinfo)

Comment: @ChrisMM None of these functions refer to what I'm asking, I mean change the position where the Scrollbar is drawn in the GUI and not move the scrollbar thumb (SetScrollInfo) or scroll the GUI (ScrollWindow).

Comment: [There are two types of scrollbars](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040510-00/?p=39413).

Comment: It's been a few days, have you solved the problem with @Remy's help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reposition a scrollbar that is built-in to a window.  You will have to disable the native scrollbar (remove the window's `WS_HSCROLL`/`WS_VSCROLL` style) and then create a separate [ScrollBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-bars) control as a child of the window.  Then you can position that child wherever you want, using the `x`/`y` parameters of `CreateWindow/Ex()` or `SetWindowPos()`.

Comment: Yes, im already creating a separate ScrollBar my doubt is how to reposition it

Comment: You can position it like you do with any other child - by using the `x`/`y` parameters of `CreateWindow/Ex()` or `SetWindowPos()`. If that is not working for you, then you need to update your question to show your actual code.

Comment: [ScrollWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindow) 
Do you know if is possible to `Scroll` the window from a given position instead scrolling the entire window? `[in] lpRect

Type: const RECT*

Pointer to the RECT structure specifying the portion of the client area to be scrolled. If this parameter is NULL, the entire client area is scrolled.` I call `GetClientRect` and modified the y position and pass it to this parameter, but it still scrolls the entire window starting from the top and not from the position I input.

Comment: @Mike I don't understand what you are asking for, or what that has to do with using a `Scrollbar` as a child. You are asking an entirely new question, so it should be asked separately as its own post.